# underfloor heating and mold forming

Tags: flooring, heating, mold, floorheating

I'll be moving into a new house soon.

The house has underfloor heating (wet system) throughout and have been told i can't put down wooden flooring.

> wood is an insulator, it will cause condensation to build.
>   And this will lead to black mold forming along the skirting boards at edge of rooms.

Is this true for modern warm houses? How can this be prevented?

Comment: Lots of good information to be found on the subject. There are probably too many factors to get a good answer here. You'll get a lot of opinion, though. http://www.hardwoodfloorsmag.com/installation/heat-wave-installing-wood-flooring-over-radiant-heating.html

Comment: My dad install Wirsbo systems for years many under hardwood floors.  It has some considerations but it is done.  [SOME MORE INFO](http://www.hardwoodinfo.com/articles/view/pro/28/239)

Answer (score 2):

It is very normal to install underfloor heating under wooden flooring, in fact in Scandinavia the majority of houses with underfloor heating have wooden floors.  Wood does insulate to a certain extent but it is no reason not to install underfloor heating. There can however be other factors such as your current floor construction that may introduce extra costs when installing the heating system that might not make it viable.